# Loop through json return undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, json, web-services

I have a webservice that returns a JSON object, but when I try to loop through it, each item in each object returns undefined

Here is the JSON object returned from the webservice

```
[{"result":14,"question":"6 - 7  مرات اسبوعيا","aID":70},{"result":29,"question":"3 - 5 مرات اسبوعيا","aID":71},{"result":41,"question":"مرة واحدة اسبوعيا","aID":72},{"result":14,"question":"1 - 3 مرات شهريا","aID":73}]
```

and here how I loop through it:

```
var resultAsJson = data.d;
$.each(resultAsJson, function (index, resObject) {
    $('#pollResults').append('<p><strong>' + resObject.result + ' ' +
                resObject.question + '</strong></p>');
    alert(resObject.question);

});
```

**------------------
UPDATE
------------------**

hi Guys,
the above code worked fine, the problem was the JSON response that I returned from the webservice was serialized as the following:

```
                Dim m_result As New Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("Result", GetType(Boolean))
            Dim lstofresult As List(Of addPollvote_Result) = Context.addPollvote(para_pid, para_aid, Date.Now, m_UID, Nothing, HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR"), Nothing, m_result).ToList
            Dim m_json As New Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
            Return m_json.Serialize(lstofresult)
```

When I removed the serialization and just returned the list, it worked perfect, see the below working code.

```
                Dim m_result As New Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("Result", GetType(Boolean))
            Dim lstofresult As List(Of addPollvote_Result) = Context.addPollvote(para_pid, para_aid, Date.Now, m_UID, Nothing, HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR"), Nothing, m_result).ToList
            Return lstofresult
```

and it worked perfect.

Comment: Looks like it works to me, as long as `resultAsJson` is populated correctly - see this jsfiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/njyvB/

Comment: @Moe9977 as @Chris stated it's probably something wrong with how you're populating `resultAsJson`. Could you post more code? What is `data.d`?

Comment: @Trevor, you are right, there was something wrong, I posted the update above.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure `resultAsJson` is actually a JSON object and not a string and it should work ([see this jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/njyvB/)) - use `resultAsJson = JSON.parse(resultAsJson)` to do the conversion from string to json object .

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be your datasource.

I would use a 'for' loop for testing purposes:

```
var resultAsJson = data.d;
var resultAsJsonLength = resultAsJson.length;

for(i=0;i<resultAsJsonLength;i++) {
    $('#pollResults').append('<p><strong>' + resultAsJson[i].result + ' ' +
    resultAsJson[i].question + '</strong></p>');

    alert(resultAsJson[i].question);
 }
```

You're going to have to provide more information about how you're accessing the data, which seems to be the foundation of your problem...

Comment: -1 - As written, this is definitely incorrect - the `index` is the index of `resObject` within `resultAsJson`, and should not be used to index into `resObject`.

Comment: This is what $.each does behind the scenes, for arrays anyway.

Comment: Yup, that's what I get for rushing through it. Should be corrected.

Comment: I was hoping the expanded form would help him troubleshoot the issue, if not solve it outright.

Comment: So now with the corrections, all it seems to do is change the jquery loop into a for loop - how might this address the question of why objects are returning undefined?

Comment: The loop and jquery are correct, but the problem was the returned the webservice json response

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go. I assume you're using jQuery:

```
// The JSON String from the web service
var jsonString = '[{"result":14,"question":"6 - 7  مرات اسبوعيا","aID":70},{"result":29,"question":"3 - 5 مرات اسبوعيا","aID":71},{"result":41,"question":"مرة واحدة اسبوعيا","aID":72},{"result":14,"question":"1 - 3 مرات شهريا","aID":73}]';

// Parse the JSON string into a JS object
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);

// Loop through, and pull what you need from it
$(jsonObj).each(function() {
    console.log(this.result + " " + this.question); 
});
```